# Convert month in String format to Number in Word Macros

Tags: vba, date, ms-word

I'm working with a Word macro that has to transform a date into another format.

input: 10 de Marzo de 2019

expected ouput: 10/03/2019

The issue is that the month of the date is in string (10 de Marzo de 2019).
I can't find the way to convert that date into dd/mm/YYYY.

Everything I have found so far converts from dd-mm-YYYY to text date.

The code above works converting from dd/mm/yyyy to date with string month, or other formats, but it never enters the isDate() function. If I remove the isDate() func, the format does not execute.

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub ChangeDates()

FoundOne = True ' loop at least once

Do While FoundOne ' loop until no date is found
    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "([0-9]{1,2}) de (*) de ([0-9]{4})"
        .Format = True
        .Forward = True
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With

    Selection.Find.Execute replace:=wdReplaceNone

    ' check the find to be sure it's a date
    If IsDate(Selection.Text) Then
        Selection.Text = Format(Selection.Text, "dd-mm-yyyy")
        Selection.Font.Color = wdColorLightOrange
        Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Else ' not a date - end loop
        FoundOne = False
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

Is there a way to achieve this? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: (part 1) I haven't worked this through, so can't add this as a useful answer. However, your search is based on three elements - a 1-or-2 digit day, a string that is hopefully a month, and a 4-digit year. If you can break that found combination using those three elements (regex?), you can then pass that through another custom function which confirms that the day part is valid against a valid month name, and then stitches the three parts together to create a date.

Comment: (part 2) If I were to create such a function, I would pass the variable `ByRef` and use the function to return a Boolean indicating if it is a valid date. Usage could be as simple as `FoundOne = MyParseDate(selectedString)`, or have an added line beneath that then (if `TRUE`) adapted the now changed `selectedString` into whatever date format you want, because your function would change it into a format acceptable by Word.

Comment: Another final thought - when looking for the Month part, consider `[Jan|Feb|someOtherValidMonthText ...etc ... ]` instead of (*), it will reduce your false positives (if you are getting any at all at the moment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried @macropod and despite it doesn't work for me, I know his solution is valid(probably some Word issues with language), a few changes should make it work, so feel free to use it too.

I went with @Cindy Meister suggestion, and this is the code. The drawback of this approach, is that you have to do two searches instead of one, but the advantage is that you use the Word Format built-in function and can change the format anytime you want.

```
Private Sub FechasEnTexto()

'We take the date to english format (dd M, Y)
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
     .Text = "([0-9]{1,2}) de (*) de ([0-9]{4})"
     .Replacement.Text = "\1 \2, \3"
     .Forward = True
     .MatchWildcards = True
     .Execute replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With


'Here we look for the english format, and proceed to apply the format desired.   
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdMove
FoundOne = True ' loop at least once


Do While FoundOne ' loop until no date is found
    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "([0-9]{1,2}) (*), ([0-9]{4})"
        .Format = True
        .Forward = True
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With

    Selection.Find.Execute replace:=wdReplaceNone


    ' check the find to be sure it's a date
    If IsDate(Selection.Text) Then
        Selection.Text = Format(Selection.Text, "dd/mm/yyyy")
        Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Else ' not a date - end loop
        FoundOne = False
    End If
Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: You refer to «probably some Word issues with language». Your example text appeared to be Spanish, so that's what I coded for. Clearly, though, if it's not all Spanish and/or your dates are not all formatted as per your example, the Find won't work - and neither will the rest of the code.

Comment: It's indeed Spanish, and the example was as I expected the format to be.

Comment: If the dates are held in fields (e.g. formfields, DATE, CREATEDATE) or ActiveX controls, a Find/Replace won't update them - you'd need to edit the actual fields and ActiveX controls. Likewise, a Find/Replace macro won't find them if they're in textboxes, headers, footers, footnotes, etc. unless it's specifically coded to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "<[0-9]{1,2} de <*> de [0-9]{4}>"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    Select Case LCase(Split(.Text, " de ")(1))
      Case "enero": i = 1
      Case "febrero": i = 2
      Case "marzo": i = 3
      Case "abril": i = 4
      Case "mayo": i = 5
      Case "junio": i = 6
      Case "julio": i = 7
      Case "agosto": i = 8
      Case "septiembre": i = 9
      Case "octubre": i = 10
      Case "noviembre": i = 11
      Case "diciembre": i = 12
      Case Else: i = 0
    End Select
    Select Case i
      Case 0
      Case Else: .Text = Split(.Text, " de ")(0) & "/" & Format(i, "00") & "/" & Split(.Text, " de ")(2)
    End Select
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for Word-VBA to recognize a date the data must match the system settings for dates. If the system settings are US-English, for example, the date in the question will not be recognized as a valid date, only dates in US-English will be recognized.

The VBA code would need to include the logic for parsing the text content as a date in the specific language. And then it would need to either convert that to a date the matches the system date so the the `Format` function works OR it would need to take care of the format conversion, as well.

Answer (score -5):

Nicolas, perhaps using **NumberFormat** before your IF statement. This way, you're setting the format to guarantee the **IsDate** expression will read as True, therefore your *IF* condition will be met.

```
Selection.NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
If IsDate(Selection.Text) Then
    Selection.Text = Format(Selection.Text, "dd-mm-yyyy")
    Selection.Font.Color = wdColorLightOrange
    Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
Else ' not a date - end loop
    FoundOne = False
End If
```

Comment: Your suggestion is irrelevant in the Word environment - Word is not Excel. It does not have a `Selection.NumberFormat` property and does not store dates as numbers. Word stores dates as literal strings.

Comment: Thanks, but I thought this was a post for Nicolas... Where all comments and Answers should be an _attempt_ to further his knowledge and confidence. I'll let you know when I post something; your comment above would be better suited there. Later, Danny.

Comment: Nicolas can't use this information as the code is in Word VBA. All this will do is confuse the situation since the suggestion cannot work in that environment. It's only noise, in this context.